# How can I add a URL at the beginning of a specific object item called through the API in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, fetch-api

I am trying to add the URL at the start of **data[{"products_picture:"..."}]** element so that it will display the picture of the product in the application. I can fetch all the information from the API and display it on the app.

Here is the API response of products:

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": "213",
            "products_id": "213",
            "products_picture": "uploads/p/p/example_1.jpg",
            "products_name": "placeholder",
        },
        {
            "id": "123",
            "products_id": "123",
            "products_picture": "uploads/p/p/example_2.jpg",
            "products_name": "placeholder3452",
        }
        ]
```

Below is my code to fetch without my attempts to add the link to products_picture:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: "follow",
  };

const siteUrl = "https://somewebsite.com/";

useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = () => {
      fetch(
        "http://apitest.dogusyapimarket.com.tr/api/v2/products",
        requestOptions
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          setProducts(result.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
    };

    getProducts();
  }, []);
```

I attempted to call *result.data* outside of the *useEffect*, but it didn't work, as it was expected. Inside the *useEffect*, I tried to access the element using *result.data.products_picture* and concatenate the *siteUrl* at the beginning of it. However, it resulted in a log of https://somewebsite.com/undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions as of now

1.Make a wrapper component on the Image to handle this

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://www.www.com';
const ImageWithBaseUrl = (imageUri, imageProps) => {
  const imageUriWithBase = `${BASE_URL}/${imageUri}`;
  return <Image {...{imageProps}} source={{uri: imageUriWithBase}}/>;
};
```

2.Make a generic function to append baseurl

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://www.www.com';
const appendBaseUrl = imageUri => {
  return `${BASE_URL}/${imageUri}`;
};

// and user it like
for(...){
  ...
  <Image source={{uri: appendBaseUrl(data[i].products_picture)}} {...{imageProps}} />;
}
```

Comment: I need it to grab the picture of the touched item in the app, instead of looping it from start to end. Based on your answer, I tried appendBaseUrl(item?.products_picture) as calling the products_name with item?.products_name works.

Comment: Actually the method I tried on my first comment worked. I just forgot to change variable name back after I tried several solutions with it. Thanks for your answer and time.